# How github "web push notifications" works?

Tags: github, websocket, real-time

It seems that github uses a polling server for real time notifications (live.github.com) on its web interface.

It seems like the technology is not Websocket based neither XHR-polling.

How is it developed ?

Comment: the nice thing about web interfaces: the source code is available to you already, and you can use the browser's developer console to see what's happening behind the scenes. use them.

Comment: I did, the solution is not clear to me. All I see is HTTP requests, but it's definitely not polling behind. I'm sure it's pushing mechanism. But can't find out how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they use HTML5 Server-Sent Events.

I found it after a while by looking at the request to live.github.com that accepts "text/event-stream"

Comment: It looks like they have switched to web sockets

Comment: @rsp I don't know anymore. I would recommend looking in chrome developer tools if you want more information. It can show web socket connections.