# How does Github instantly update it's web interface?

Tags: github, websocket, push-notification

There are things on Github that update almost instantly. One example is when a merged branch is pushed, it's corresponding pull request will update to a `merged` status almost immediately.

[image: Realtime Github pull request status update]

I assumed this was a WebSocket, but I can't see any websockets in my devtools (or Wireshark), then I thought it might be the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API), but don't I need to opt-in to allow that to work?

I'm asking because I'm looking for a means to push (near) realtime updates to my users within a web app, and I'm curious how Github do it.

Comment: Maybe this will help? But it's for notifications though https://xtreemsolution.com/blog/How-to-make-real-time-notification-system-using-socketio-and-nodejs

Comment: @marsnebulasoup it appears that Github are doing this *without* websockets though, as there are no websockets that appear in the `Network` tab in devtools.

Comment: I get that, but that doesn't mean *you* can't use websockets, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Github.com uses websocket for notifications, but let's see where the websocket is called

Github.com uses [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Specifically, for notification, they are using [shared workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) which is why you don't see the network activity in the network tabs of your browsing context.

In order to see shared workers, in a new tab type: "chrome://inspect/#workers", you would see something like this :

[image]

Click on inspect, and go to networks tabs :

[image]

If nothing shows up, click "terminate" and refresh your other tab page (github.com) so that it comes up again

[This file](https://github.githubassets.com/assets/behaviors-80bafcf6.js) (behaviors-xxxx.js) loads the workers url :

```js
this.worker = new SharedWorker("/socket-worker.js","socket-worker-v7"),
```

The worker is loaded via this script: https://github.com/socket-worker.js

Comment: also an interesting note, it seems that [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388923/2614364) they used HTML5 Server-Sent Events but switched to websocket later

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I was beginning to think they had cracked `extrasensory perception`.